# OfficeToPDF gets stuck when called from Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, pdf-conversion

We are using [OfficeToPDF](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF) to convert MS Office documents to PDF. This basically simply opens the corresponding MS Office app and uses the 'Save as' to convert to PDF. This is used from a Java application which runs in a Payara server started from a Windows Service.

It properly does its job in Windows 2012 server before patching in Spring this year. After Windows patching the officeToPDF and Windows processes get started but then stall and get stuck without converting and without closing the processes again. In Windows 2019 server its the same issue.

When called from CMD, however, it properly does its job. Also after patching or Windows 2019 it works from CMD.

Any idea why that is? I think its any permission change.

Thanks